# Getting an upload error of ESP8266 using Arduino IDE with this report

Tags: upload, esp8266

The report is like this :

Executable segment sizes:

```
ICACHE : 32768           - flash instruction cache 

IROM   : 252980          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR) 

IRAM   : 28261   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (IRAM_ATTR, ISRs...) 

DATA   : 1560  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 

RODATA : 2484  ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 

BSS    : 26704 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 

Sketch uses 285285 bytes (27%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 30748 bytes (37%) of dynamic memory, leaving 51172 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
"C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\python3\3.7.2-post1/python3" "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.1/tools/upload.py" --chip esp8266 --port "COM4" --baud "115200" ""  --before default_reset --after hard_reset write_flash 0x0 "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino-sketch-A88D8C3CC17CAE2361CEB8CD194D0EE6/sketch_dec24a.ino.bin"
esptool.py v3.0
Serial port COM4
Connecting...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\3.0.1/tools/upload.py", line 66, in <module>
    esptool.main(cmdline)
  File "C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 3552, in main
    esp.connect(args.before, args.connect_attempts)
  File "C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 519, in connect
    last_error = self._connect_attempt(mode=mode, esp32r0_delay=False)
  File "C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 499, in _connect_attempt
    self.sync()
  File "C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 438, in sync
    timeout=SYNC_TIMEOUT)
  File "C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 376, in command
    self.write(pkt)
  File "C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.1/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 339, in write
    self._port.write(buf)
  File "C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/3.0.1/tools/pyserial\serial\serialwin32.py", line 325, in write
    raise SerialTimeoutException('Write timeout')
serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

I already installed all drivers and needed libraries.